# How to handle multiple keyboard inputs in kivy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

so im developing this game, which is a platformer, so im working on the movements now, the problem is:

i can move the player to the left and right side, i can also jump, however i can't move and jump at the same time, like, while im moving forward i want to be able to jump forward and that would require me to press the forward and the up buttons.
i've tried many ways to get this but with no success and i haven't found this issue googling around, so...  here's the minimal code to help things out.
the issue is the player either jump or move, it doesn't do  both when i press the up and forward keys.

Main.py

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.properties import Clock

from Player import PlayerImage

class LevelOneLayout(MDFloatLayout):
    pass


class LevelOne(MDScreen):
    from PlayerAction import _keyboard_closed, _on_keyboard_down, _on_keyboard_up

    gravity_force = 1800

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)    
   
     
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup, 1/60)


    def setup(self, dt):

    self.player_image = PlayerImage()
    self.add_widget(self.player_image)


    Clock.schedule_interval(self.game_gravity, 1/30)


    def game_gravity(self, dt):
        if self.player_image.on_air:
            self.player_image.player_gravity_vel -= self.gravity_force * 1/30
            self.player_image.y += self.player_image.player_gravity_vel * 1/30 

        if self.player_image.y <= 60:
            self.player_image.y = 60
            self.player_image.player_gravity_vel = 0
            self.player_image.on_air = False


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"

        return


MainApp().run()
```

Main.kv

```
LevelOne:

    LevelOneLayout:


<LevelOneLayout>:


<PlayerImage>:
    source: "player_77x100.png"
    size_hint: None, None
    size: "77dp", "100dp"
    x: "0dp"
    y: "50dp"
```

Player.py

```
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.animation import Animation
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout


class PlayerImage(Image):

    texture_side = "right"

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.velx = 20

        self.player_gravity_vel = 0
        self.on_air = False


    def move_left(self, state, *args):
        if state: 
            self.x -= self.velx
            self.texture_left()
            self.forced_dash = False
        else:
            return None


    def move_right(self, state, *args):
        if state:
            self.x += self.velx
            self.texture_right()
            self.forced_dash = False
        else:
            return None


    def jump(self, state, *args):
        if not self.on_air and state:
            self.player_gravity_vel = 830
            self.on_air = True
        else:
            return None



    def texture_left(self):
        if self.texture.tex_coords[0] == 0: 
            self.texture.flip_horizontal()
            self.texture.ask_update(self.update_texture)
            self.texture_side = "left"


    def texture_right(self):
        if self.texture.tex_coords[0] == 1: 
            self.texture.flip_horizontal()
            self.texture.ask_update(self.update_texture)
            self.texture_side = "right"


    def update_texture(self, texture):
        self.texture = None
        self.texture = texture
```

PlayerAction.py

```
key_state = True


def _keyboard_closed(self):
    self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
    self._keyboard = None


def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, *args):

    if keycode[1] == "up":
        self.player_image.jump(key_state)

    if keycode[1] == "left":
        self.player_image.move_left(key_state)

    elif keycode[1] == "right":
        self.player_image.move_right(key_state)

    return True


def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode, *args):

    key_state = False

    if keycode[1] == "up":
        self.player_image.jump(key_state)

    if keycode[1] == "left":
        self.player_image.move_left(key_state)

    elif keycode[1] == "right":
        self.player_image.move_right(key_state)

    return True
```

[image: Player Image]

Comment: It looks like your code relies on the fact that when you hold a key down, you repeatedly get new keypress events from that key. However, when you hold a key down then press another, the second key overrides that. You should instead not rely on this and handle the key up/down state within you program: in the keyboard_down event store somewhere the "left key is down" state, and in the keyboard_up event clear that state. Then Clock.schedule_interval a function "update_character" which moves it left if the left key is down, right if the right key is down, jumps if the jump key is down etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help Mr.inclement, i had asked this in the kivy group support and with Mr.ElliotG's help and your i got everything working, i'll post my solution here in case someone else stumbles on this problem, once again thank you for the help.

Answer (score 1):

so for an example that manages multiple key presses i recommend this link:
https://groups.google.com/g/kivy-users/c/b0Qmv160GBk

which is the answer to this question i made in the kivy group support, so i've changed a bit the code to suit my code and with Mr.inclements help i did this:
i've put the changes in blockquotes.

Main.py file:

```
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import MDScreen
from kivymd.uix.floatlayout import MDFloatLayout
from kivy.properties import Clock

from Player import PlayerImage

class LevelOneLayout(MDFloatLayout):
    pass


class LevelOne(MDScreen):
    from PlayerAction import _keyboard_closed, _on_keyboard_down, _on_keyboard_up, """process_keys"""

    gravity_force = 1800

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)    

 
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.setup, 1/60)


    def setup(self, dt):

        self.player_image = PlayerImage()
        self.add_widget(self.player_image)


        Clock.schedule_interval(self.game_gravity, 1/30)
        """Clock.schedule_interval(self.process_keys, 1/30)"""


    def game_gravity(self, dt):
        if self.player_image.on_air:
            self.player_image.player_gravity_vel -= self.gravity_force * 1/30
            self.player_image.y += self.player_image.player_gravity_vel * 1/30 

        if self.player_image.y <= 60:
            self.player_image.y = 60
            self.player_image.player_gravity_vel = 0
            self.player_image.on_air = False


class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = "Dark"
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = "Red"

        return


MainApp().run()
```

PlayerAction.py File:

```
"""pressed_keys = set()"""


def _keyboard_closed(self):

    self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_down = self._on_keyboard_down)

    """self._keyboard.unbind(on_key_up = self._on_keyboard_up)"""

    self._keyboard = None


def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, *args):    

    """pressed_keys.add(keycode[1])"""

    return True


def _on_keyboard_up(self, keyboard, keycode, *args): 

    """pressed_keys.remove(keycode[1])"""    

    return True

"""
def process_keys(self, dt):

    if pressed_keys.issuperset({'up', 'right'}):

        self.player_image.jump()

        self.player_image.move_right()


    elif pressed_keys.issuperset({'up', 'left'}):

        self.player_image.jump()

        self.player_image.move_left()


    elif pressed_keys.issuperset({'left', 'up'}):

        self.player_image.move_left()

        self.player_image.up()


    elif pressed_keys.issuperset({'right', 'up'}):

        self.player_image.move_right()

        self.player_image.up()


    elif pressed_keys.issuperset({'up'}):

        self.player_image.jump()


    elif pressed_keys.issuperset({'left'}):

        self.player_image.move_left()


    elif pressed_keys.issuperset({'right'}):

        self.player_image.move_right()
"""
```

Player.py file:

in the player.py file i just deleted the "state" parameter from the "jump", "move_left" and "move_right" methods, since i've deleted the "key_state" variable from the PlayerAction.py file, i wouldn't need the "state" parameter in here.

Notice that the multiple key presses example provided in the kivy support group doesnt use a Clock to call the "process_key" method, instead it just calls from the "_on_keyboard_down" method, however doing this way still makes you feel like the second key is overriding the first, so i've tried using here Mr.inclement's answer by calling the "process_key" method using the Clock, and it works. that it.